# No error occurs even if not overriding abstract setter and deleter in a child class in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties, abstract-class, abstract-methods

I defined the abstract getter, setter and deleter with `@abstractmethod` and `@property`, `@name.setter` or `@name.deleter` in **`Person` abstract class** as shown below. *I use **Python 3.8.5**:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Person(ABC):
    
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def name(self): # Abstract getter
        pass

    @name.setter
    @abstractmethod
    def name(self, name): # Abstract setter
        pass

    @name.deleter
    @abstractmethod
    def name(self): # Abstract deleter
        pass
```

Then, I extended **`Person` abstract class** with **`Student` class** and overrode only the abstract getter in **`Student` class** and instantiated **`Student` class** as shown below:

```py
class Student(Person): # Extends "Person" class
    
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name
    
    @property
    def name(self): # Overrides only abstract getter
        return self._name

obj = Student("John") # Instantiates "Student" class
print(obj.name)
```

But, there was no error getting the proper result below even though I didn't override the abstract setter and deleter:

```
John
```

Basically, an abstract method needs to be overridden in a child class otherwise there is an error when the child class is instantiated but there was no error in above case.

Actually, when I didn't override the abstract getter in **`Student` class** and instantiated **`Student` class** as shown below:

```py
class Student(Person): # Extends "Person" class
    
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name

obj = Student("John") # Instantiates "Student" class
print(obj.name)
```

I got the error below:

> TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Student with abstract methods name

So, are there anything wrong?

Comment: The problem is that all three abstract methods have the same name, and you do implement a concrete method of that name in the child, so all three are covered by that.

Comment: Over the last few days, I've seen you've been adding "in Python" to quite a few titles. While that is your prerogative for questions you asked, note that it is unnecessary. Tagging your question [tag:python] automatically includes the word "python" in the title. Please refrain from doing so to other people's questions, especially if they've already been edited by someone else to remove the tag from the title.